# mysql table multi foreign key cascade

Tags: mysql, sql, jpa, foreign-keys, cascade

Let's say I have 4 tables related as below diagram

`ad` **-->** `advertisable` **<--** `advertisable_product` **-->** `product`

The 3 `->` means as below, all of them are `OneToOne` related

1. `ad` has a FK to `advertisable` (nullable)
2. `advertisable_product` has a FK to `advertisable`
3. `advertisable_product` has a FK to `product`

I have set up **on delete cascade** constraint on `3.`

**The question is**: When the `product` is deleted, `advertisable_product` is deleted automatically by the on delete cascade constraint, but **how to make it also delete the `advertisable` and set the FK in `ad` to null.**

The only way I can figure out is to write a trigger to do that. Is there any better solution or better design to achieve that?

Any advice or comment are welcome, Thanks ~

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. According to the FK logic there mught be another product tied to the **advertisable**.

Imagine there is 1 advertisable - "A1" and 2 products "P1" and "P2".
**advertisable_product** has 2 records

A1 P1

A1 P2

Now you delete "P1". The "A1 P1" is deleted by the cascade but "A1" can't be deleted because it's used in the "A1 P2"

Comment: Hi StanislavL, the advertisable and advertisable_product is OneToOne, so ONLY A1 P1 is possiable, there is no A1 P2

Comment: FK doesn't know about this. It's not possible logically from your business logic but DB supposes it's possible according to FKs

Comment: Okay, I got your point. So, the only way to do this is to write the logic manually, right?

Comment: You can define a ON DELETE trigger for the advertisable_product  and remove the row in advertisable